# hold zero expression meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, australian-english

what's the meaning of  ***long hold zero*** in the following sentence

although I was not able to **long hold zero** to turn off the engine after this

Comment: Native speaker here, never heard that term.  It sounds like a forum post, is it possible this is an error?  If not, please edit to include more context.  (My guess would be to press the "zero" button for a long time to deactivate an engine in a video game.)

Comment: @MikeKozar it's an email I've received from Australian guy

Answer (score 1):

@user11628 answered in a comment:

> My guess would be to **press** the "**zero**" button for a **long** time to deactivate an engine in a video game.

The answer cannot be guaranteed to be 100% correct, as there is insufficient context.